# Scaling Backends Automatically - Appengine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have a pull-queue which runs on the backend. I invoke it from a frontend when the spike is high.

The pull-queue has tens of thousands of tasks and it takes a while. One single frontend request starts the processing.

I am looking to start more of the backends from my code so that they can all pull tasks from the pull-queues and start executing them. However, I am not clear on how to do that.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to migrate your code from using backends to modules: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/modules/

Then you can use Basic scaling to specify the maximum number of instances that you want automatically created.

UPDATE:

With pull queues you have to implement the load balancing logic yourself.

Comment: Basic scaling will balance based on the requests. Since there is no requests here, I need manual scaling which is better. However, I do not see a method to stop a particular module. This is what I was thinking. When I see about 10k tasks, I create an instance for each 3k tasks which is round about 4. I start 4 and in /_ah/start, I start pulling all the queues. Now the tasks are complete and I am looking to stop. How do I stop the module which knows that it is done? I do not see stop_me :)? I see numinstances which can stop any random instance which may be executing tasks. Thanks.

Comment: Tasks in the queue are executed by creating requests on the target module.

Comment: You do not need to start or stop instances. You can set the desired execution rate on your queue and the maximum number of instances that you want to be created. This is it. If a queue cannot keep up with the desired execution rate, the scheduler will create more instances - automatically. When the load drops, the scheduler will stop the redundant instances - also automatically.

Comment: These are pull queues and not push queues. Can I still set the execution rate and max instances? How do I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you use a pull queue if the tasks run on a backend? You can trigger a request from your front-end to add all the tasks to the push queue, and then the load balancing will take care of itself. With pull queues you have to implement this load balancing logic yourself.

Comment: We collate few tasks based on tag in pull queues and batch process them (the third party provider dependency)

Comment: You can use a Datastore instead of Task Queue for this purpose. A single task will go through the entities to collate them, and for each "collated" entity add a task to the push queue for execution. This seems like a much simpler design to me.

Comment: For 100k tasks, it would add 100k read/write calls. Also these tasks are sporadic.